# Using a specific SQL script in Excel to update hundreds of rows of data

Tags: sql-server, excel

I need help transferring lots of rows of data from excel to a SQL script/s and entering them to server. I normally copy my scripts from notepad and past them onto my SQL script area in APEX.

This is my SQL script:

```
update shipment
set shipmt_account_classification = '1771453.2253 210 00022 068566 2D SEMXKX 000227M42008 N0002217CSSNN68'
where orders_serial_key = 991573
and shipment_number = 1;
```

This is the excel data

[image: Excel data]. 
(Over 500 rows)

Each `funds`, `OSK`, and `SN` for every row needs to be updated onto above SQL script.

This is my SQL server that I past my scripts into. 
[image: This is my SQL server that I past my scripts into.]

I usually copy and past every row of data individually onto the script, which takes forever.

I am sure there is an easier way of doing this.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In a separate worksheet, set the first three columns A-C to be equal to the three data columns in your example. Then, in cols E-K, use these formulas (per row 2):

```
E  'UPDATE shipment SET shipmt_account_classification =
F  ="'" &A2&"'"
G  'where orders_serial_key =
H   =B2
I   'and shipment_number = 
J   =C2
K   ';
```

Copy down for the full 500 rows, and then select and copy all the data in cols E-K and paste them into your query editor. You should have all the udpates required in a single script.